Combining observables in Java
I  have a list of names. (capturadosSp)
I want to do a request to get a Observable list.
Then i want to know if a name in capturados is  in the Observable list.
If so i want to do a new request with the name and with the new objetc set the
properties in the object with the same name in de Observable list
Finally return the list
The code is not reproducible. If it was I wouldn't ask
     capturadosSp = List.of("name1", "name2"...)

     repository.getPokemonList(0, 25).map( list -> { //return an Observable

            for(Pokemon pokemon: list.getPokemonList()){
                if(capturadosSp.contains(pokemon.getName())){
                    
                    repository.getPokemon(pokemon.getName()).map(p-> pokemon.setWeigth(p.getWeight()));
                                            
                }
            }

            return list;
                })
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(
                    onNext -> {
                      
                     pokemonList.postValue(onNext.getPokemonList());
                },
                onError -> {},
                () -> { }

That works but im subscribing within the first callback and i think its not good to testting
    repo.getPokemonListCall(0,15).enqueue(new Callback<PokemonList>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<PokemonList> call, 
                   Response<PokemonList> response) {
                ArrayList<Pokemon> list = (response.body().getPokemonList());
                for(Pokemon p: list){
                    if(capturadosSp.contains(p.getNombre())){
                        repo.getPokemon(p.getNombre()).map(pok-> { //request to firebase
                            p.setAltura(pok.getAltura());
                            p.setImgUrl(pok.getImgUrl());

                            return p;
                        }).subscribe(
                           next-> {
                               System.out.println(next);
                        }, error ->{},
                           ()-> pokemonList.postValue(list));
                    }
                }
            }

But i think this is an antippattern.

Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others to provide an answer faster.
Please show your attempts you have tried and the problems/error messages you get from your attempts.
